Android 15 Certificate CA installation
On my GOOGLE PIXEL phone running ANDROID 15, I want to integrate a ROOT certificate for various applications. For example, I have a corporate proxy that performs SSL filtering or simply want to test with MITM PROXY.
I navigate to Settings > Security & Privacy > Enhanced Security & Privacy > Encryption & Credentials > Install a Certificate > CA Certificate.
At this point, I get a warning message:
"Your data will not be private. CA certificates are used by websites, apps, and VPNs [...]"
I click on "Install anyway".
I'm prompted to authenticate once more.
Next, I reach the file selection screen, where I choose my file.
After clicking on "Install Certificate", I'm redirected to the "CA Certificate" selection screen with no error message or any further confirmation.
I’ve also tried this on a Samsung S22.
The phone is not rooted and is in factory settings.
Does anyone have an idea? Is there a checkbox I need to enable somewhere? Is it no longer possible to perform this operation? There’s nothing about it in Google’s documentation.
